# duplicar registros de una tabla sql con un ID a otro ID de la misma tabla

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Amigos espero puedan ayudarme requiero hacer lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito duplicar la primer tabla con los registros que pertenecen al campo esp_id=17302.es decir todos estos registros pertenecen a este campo.
Necesito duplicar estos campos pero al id con el campo:esp_id=35662

trate de hacer esto :

```
INSERT INTO SI_Especificacion_Restriccion
(esp_id,eje_id,tir_id,epr_nombre,epr_orden,epr_valor1,epr_valor2,epr_titulo,epr_es_gra,epr_fec_alta,epr_fec_mod,usu_id_alta,usu_id_mod,tnm_id,sello_id,epr_no_juzgar,gra_id,nod_id,tca_id,epr_no_decimales) 
SELECT esp_id,eje_id,tir_id,epr_nombre,epr_orden,epr_valor1,epr_valor2,epr_titulo,epr_es_gra,epr_fec_alta,epr_fec_mod,usu_id_alta,usu_id_mod,tnm_id,sello_id,epr_no_juzgar,gra_id,nod_id,tca_id,epr_no_decimales
FROM SI_Especificacion_Restriccion WHERE esp_id in (35662,17302)
```

pero se duplican en la misma tabla con los registros.

Comment: No logro entender del todo. ¿Quieres introducir los valores que cumplan una condición en otra tabla y que no te mantenga el id? Si es eso, entonces tienes que tener en cuenta que en el insert el primer campo que le estas metiendo es el id que tiene en la primera tabla

Comment: la imagen es de 2 consultas 1 tiene datos ( que es la de arriba que tiene el campo esp_id=17302) y la otra no lo que necesito es pasar los datos de arriba  a la de abajo(donde esta vacio pero con el id distinto esp_id=35662). . .pero en la de abajo van con otro ID distinto al final las 2 consultas me deben traer la misma informacion . . .  no se si me explico. . .  saludos.

Comment: Ah! ¿Osea que necesitas duplicar los datos a la misma tabla con un id diferente?

Comment: exactamente . . . intente el script de arriba pero se duplica solo en la de arriba. . .

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, **¿podrías poner un ejemplo con datos de entrada y cómo debería quedar la otra tabla tras hacer el trabajo?** Por favor, sin capturas de pantalla, en texto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas son los registros del campo `esp_id=17302` pero cambiando la clave, por ello la consulta es un simple `select` de todos los campos con el `where` correspondiente, pero sustituyendo el campo `esp_id` por el deseado en el `select`.

```
INSERT INTO SI_Especificacion_Restriccion
(esp_id,eje_id,tir_id,epr_nombre,epr_orden,epr_valor1,epr_valor2,epr_titulo,epr_es_gra,epr_fec_alta,epr_fec_mod,usu_id_alta,usu_id_mod,tnm_id,sello_id,epr_no_juzgar,gra_id,nod_id,tca_id,epr_no_decimales) 
SELECT 35662,eje_id,tir_id,epr_nombre,epr_orden,epr_valor1,epr_valor2,epr_titulo,epr_es_gra,epr_fec_alta,epr_fec_mod,usu_id_alta,usu_id_mod,tnm_id,sello_id,epr_no_juzgar,gra_id,nod_id,tca_id,epr_no_decimales
FROM SI_Especificacion_Restriccion 
WHERE esp_id = 17302
```

Comment: perfecto amigo me ayudo muchisimo , eso es exactamente lo que requeria  ya pude duplicar los datos . muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Por si le sirve a alguien, en mi caso necesitaba duplicar todos los registros de una tabla cambiando una llave foranea, lo que hice fue exportar a SQL todos los registros que necesitaba (excepto el campo id y la llave foranea que necesitaba cambiar) y en un block de notas agregué masivamente la llave foranea que necesitaba al final de cada línea (tomando como comodín para reemplazar el "),"), luego ejecuté el insert dejando el id autoincrementable y listo, sé que parece complicado pero en realidad es muy sencillo.

ANTES DE LA EDICIÓN

```
INSERT INTO "nomina_nomina" ("valor_mesada", "persona_id", "pagado", "banco_id", "eps_id", "revisado", "grupo_id") VALUES
(0.00,  882,    0.00,   2,  2,  'f',    3),
(0.00,  926,    0.00,   2,  2,  'f',    1),
```

DESPUÉS DE LA EDICIÓN
Aumenté al final el campo "liquidación_id" y en los registros ",2"

```
INSERT INTO "nomina_nomina" ("valor_mesada", "persona_id", "pagado", "banco_id", "eps_id", "revisado", "grupo_id", "liquidacion_id") VALUES
(0.00,  882,    0.00,   2,  2,  'f',    3,2),
(0.00,  926,    0.00,   2,  2,  'f',    1,2),
```